# Bind a controller to handle bad request in sails js

Tags: sails.js

I'm new to sails js and still exploring the framework. My question is that, can we bind an action inside a controller whenever there is a bad request from front end? rather than calling in the response page, the customized controller is instead called.

Please shed some light. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You can always call `res.badRequest()`, which will return a 400 status response to the browser.
2. You can create a [service](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Services) to house custom "bad request" response code, and call it from any controller.  For example, make a **api/services/ResponseService.js** file with a method like:

   ```
   badRequest: function(req, res) {
       return res.send(400, "You've been bad!");
   }
   ```

   and call it from your controller like `ResponseService.badRequest(req, res);`
3. If you're using Sails v0.10.x, you can customize the default `badRequest` response by modifying **api/responses/badRequest.js**.  This has all the benefits of #2, while allowing you to use the semantics of #1 (i.e. just calling `res.badRequest()`) and avoiding the overhead of a separate service module.

Comment: thanks for the respond scott. Just a follow up question, is it a good practice to modify files inside responses?